# How to assign data to a variable from axios get() response

Tags: reactjs, http, async-await, axios, get

I am trying to use Express (axios) to build a React app.

I was able to get an array of objects from MongoDB using get() method. Currently the list is printed out to the console. How can I assign it to a variable so that I could use that array for further actions?

```
useEffect(() => {
    const expensesListResp = async () => {
      await axios.get('http://localhost:4000/app/expenseslist')
      .then(
        response => console.log(response.data))
    }
    expensesListResp();
  }, []);
```

Many thanks!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I save the axios response to variable, to be used outside axios?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56719812/how-do-i-save-the-axios-response-to-variable-to-be-used-outside-axios)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can assign it in the following way, let's say you have an array `posts`:

```
const [posts, setPosts] = useState([]);

useEffect(() => {
  axios.get('url')
  .then(res => setPosts(res.data))
  .catch(err => console.log(err));
}, [])
```

In your code, you can do it in this way:

```
const [resultArray, setResultArray] = useState([]);

useEffect(() => {
    const expensesListResp = async () => {
      await axios.get('http://localhost:4000/app/expenseslist')
      .then(
        response => setResultArray(response.data))
    }
    expensesListResp();
  }, []);
```

Comment: It works and is a great solution! Many thanks

Comment: From where did you import useState? is it react?

Comment: @PurnajyotiBhaumik Yes, it's imported from React Hooks.

Answer (score 2):

I am assuming that you have data printed on the `console.log(response.data)` and you want it to be assigned to a variable so that you can use it right?

if that's the case you are already using `async` function just name it with whatever variable name you want it to be before `await`.

```
for example:

const expensesListResp = async () => {
      const "your variable name" = await axios.get('http://localhost:4000/app/expenseslist')
    }
```

you can also save that variable in your state, if you want to use that variable data throughout your application.